# php help redirect contact form to thank you page

Tags: php, contact-form

Currently my contact form responds with a message. I would like to change it so it redirects to a thank you page instead. Can someone help me adjust my code accordingly?

I know I either need to do window.location or headerLocation but I'm not sure where to insert it in this particular template to make it work.

```
<?php
include('SMTPClass.php');

$use_smtp = '0';
$emailto = 'email@email.com';

    // retrieve from parameters
    $emailfrom = isset($_POST["email"]) ? $_POST["email"] : "";
    $nocomment = isset($_POST["nocomment"]) ? $_POST["nocomment"] : "";
    $subject = 'Inquiry';
    $message = '';
    $response = '';
    $response_fail = 'There was an error verifying your details.';

        // Honeypot captcha
        if($nocomment == '') {

            $params = $_POST;
            foreach ( $params as $key=>$value ){

                if(!($key == 'ip' || $key == 'emailsubject' || $key == 'url' || $key == 'emailto' || $key == 'nocomment' || $key == 'v_error' || $key == 'v_email')){

                    $key = ucwords(str_replace("-", " ", $key));

                    if ( gettype( $value ) == "array" ){
                        $message .= "$key: \n";
                        foreach ( $value as $two_dim_value )
                        $message .= "...$two_dim_value<br>";
                    }else {
                        $message .= $value != '' ? "$key: $value\n" : '';
                    }
                }
            }

        $response = sendEmail($subject, $message, $emailto, $emailfrom);

        } else {

            $response = $response_fail;

        }

    echo $response;

// Run server-side validation
function sendEmail($subject, $content, $emailto, $emailfrom) {

    $from = $emailfrom;
    $response_sent = 'Thank you. Your messsage has been received.';
    $response_error = 'Error. Please try again.';
    $subject =  filter($subject);
    $url = "Origin Page: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    $ip = "IP Address: ".$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    $message = $content."\n$ip\r\n$url";

    // Validate return email & inform admin
    $emailto = filter($emailto);

    // Setup final message
    $body = wordwrap($message);

    if($use_smtp == '1'){

        $SmtpServer = 'SMTP SERVER';
        $SmtpPort = 'SMTP PORT';
        $SmtpUser = 'SMTP USER';
        $SmtpPass = 'SMTP PASSWORD';

        $to = $emailto;
        $SMTPMail = new SMTPClient ($SmtpServer, $SmtpPort, $SmtpUser, $SmtpPass, $from, $to, $subject, $body);
        $SMTPChat = $SMTPMail->SendMail();
        $response = $SMTPChat ? $response_sent : $response_error;

    } else {

        // Create header
        $headers = "From: $from\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n";

        // Send email
        $mail_sent = @mail($emailto, $subject, $body, $headers);
        $response = $mail_sent ? $response_sent : $response_error;

    }
    return $response;
}

// Remove any un-safe values to prevent email injection
function filter($value) {
    $pattern = array("/\n/", "/\r/", "/content-type:/i", "/to:/i", "/from:/i", "/cc:/i");
    $value = preg_replace($pattern, "", $value);
    return $value;
}

exit;

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your sendEmail() function you can remove this line:

```
$response_sent = 'Thank you. Your messsage has been received.';
```

Then change those 2 lines:

```
$response = $SMTPChat ? $response_sent : $response_error;
//Becomes:
$response = $SMTPChat ? true : $response_error;

$response = $mail_sent ? $response_sent : $response_error;
//Becomes:
$response = $mail_sent ? true : $response_error;
```

So that `return $response;` will return TRUE if everything was fine

And then change `echo $response;` To something like

```
if($response===true){
  $url="thankyou.php"
  if(!headers_sent()){
    header("location:".$url);
  }else{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.location='".$url."';</script>";
  }
  exit();
}else{
  echo $response;
}
```

Explaination:
We will use $response_sent to check if everything was successful or not.
If $response_sent is an absolute TRUE (triple =) we tell the script to redirect the user, or ELSE we echo the error message just like it is right now.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. I do have a follow up question however: Can you think of anything in the last code snippet you posted that would lead to a syntax error?

Comment: i didn't test it, but beside a missing quote or something like this i don't think so. But beside syntax, you can figure the logic behind. Glad i could help.

Comment: i just notice i'm missng a closing bracket on `if(!headers_sent(){` it should read `if(!headers_sent()){` I will edit my answer.